# What does LayoutInflater in Android do?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-inflate

What is the use of [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) in Android?

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729036/what-is-a-layoutinflater-and-how-do-i-use-it-properly/51729037#51729037) one helps.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

When you use a custom view in a `ListView` you must define the row layout.
You create an xml where you place android widgets and then in the adapter's code you have to do something like this:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<MyObject> objects) extends ArrayAdapter {
  super(context, 1, objects);
  /* We get the inflator in the constructor */
  mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view;
  /* We inflate the xml which gives us a view */
  view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_custom_row, parent, false);

  /* Get the item in the adapter */
  MyObject myObject = getItem(position);

  /* Get the widget with id name which is defined in the xml of the row */
  TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

  /* Populate the row's xml with info from the item */
  name.setText(myObject.getName());

  /* Return the generated view */
  return view;
}
```

Read more in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Comment: Ideally you should first test convertView to see if you can recycle a resource, so `View view = convertView; if (view == null) { view = mInflater.... }`

Comment: I don't think this answer really explains what a `LayoutInflater` is, although it explains where to use it. The answer 1-down is better.

Comment: This does not explain what a LayoutInflater is. It explains how to use it.

Comment: I'm looking for the explanation of LayoutInflater.

Comment: @Player1 You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729036/what-is-layoutinflater-and-how-do-i-use-it-properly/51729037#51729037) post

Answer (score 335):

The [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) class is used to instantiate the contents of layout XML files into their corresponding View objects.

In other words, it takes an XML file as input and builds the View objects from it.

Comment: What i was looking for is the "in other words" part since the top part is already in the API docs

Comment: This still seems pretty abstract to me. So, let's say I have a `single_list_item.xml` file for a each line of a `ListView`. Is the use of that XML file sort of like an inflater?

Comment: in fact, the API docs say it all. Instantiating the contents of XML is the precise description. Sometimes we read too deep into the text and miss the obvious

Answer (score 257):

## What does [`LayoutInflator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) do?

When I first started Android programming, I was really confused by `LayoutInflater` and `findViewById`. Sometimes we used one and sometimes the other.

- `LayoutInflater` is used to create a new `View` (or `Layout`) object from one of your xml layouts.
- `findViewById` just gives you a reference to a view than has already been created. You might think that you haven't created any views yet, but whenever you call `setContentView` in `onCreate`, the activity's layout along with its subviews gets inflated (created) behind the scenes.

So if the view already exists, then use `findViewById`. If not, then create it with a `LayoutInflater`.

## Example

Here is a mini project I made that shows both `LayoutInflater` and `findViewById` in action. With no special code, the layout looks like this.

[image]

The blue square is a custom layout inserted into the main layout with `include` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41498846/3681880) for more). It was inflated automatically because it is part of the content view. As you can see, there is nothing special about the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Now let's inflate (create) another copy of our custom layout and add it in.

[image]

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, mainLayout, false);
```

To inflate the new view layout, all I did was tell the inflater the name of my xml file (`my_layout`), the parent layout that I want to add it to (`mainLayout`), and that I don't actually want to add it yet (`false`). (I could also set the parent to `null`, but then the layout parameters of my custom layout's root view would be ignored.)

Here it is again in context.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // inflate the main layout for the activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get a reference to the already created main layout
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_layout);

        // inflate (create) another copy of our custom layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, mainLayout, false);

        // make changes to our custom layout and its subviews
        myLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
        TextView textView = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("New Layout");

        // add our custom layout to the main layout
        mainLayout.addView(myLayout);
    }
}
```

Notice how `findViewById` is used only after a layout has already been inflated.

## Supplemental Code

Here is the xml for the example above.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <!-- Here is the inserted layout -->
    <include layout="@layout/my_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*my_layout.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="My Layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## When do you need LayoutInflater

- The most common time most people use it is in a `RecyclerView`. (See these `RecyclerView` examples for a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example-with-a-linearlayout-like-the-old-listview) or a [grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40587168/3681880).) You have to inflate a new layout for every single visible item in the list or grid.
- You also can use a layout inflater if you have a complex layout that you want to add programmatically (like we did in our example). You could do it all in code, but it is much easier to define it in xml first and then just inflate it.

Comment: Hello sir, If I have more then one view within main_activity.xml , then how can i set the external.xml view in main_activity with center layout_gravity.

Comment: Is mylayout a View type or LinearLayout type?

Comment: @HSSingh, `myLayout` is a View, though I could have inflated it as a RelativeLayout (see my_layout.xml). After it is inflated I add it as a subview of the LinearLayout parent (that is, `mainLayout`).

Answer (score 33):

LayoutInflater.inflate() provides a means to convert a res/layout/*.xml file defining a view into an actual View object usable in your application source code.

basic two steps: get the inflater and then inflate the resource

How do you get the inflater?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

How do you get the view assuming the xml file is "list_item.xml"?

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is another example similar to the previous one, but extended to further demonstrate inflate parameters and dynamic behavior it can provide.

Suppose your ListView row layout can have variable number of TextViews. So first you inflate the base item View (just like the previous example), and then loop dynamically adding TextViews at run-time. Using android:layout_weight additionally aligns everything perfectly.

Here are the Layouts resources:

**list_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/field1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/field2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**schedule_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Override **getView** method in extension of BaseAdapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View lst_item_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) lst_item_view.findViewById(R.id.field1);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) lst_item_view.findViewById(R.id.field2);
    t1.setText("some value");
    t2.setText("another value");

    // dinamically add TextViews for each item in ArrayList list_schedule
    for(int i = 0; i < list_schedule.size(); i++){
        View schedule_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_layout, (ViewGroup) lst_item_view, false);
        ((TextView)schedule_view).setText(list_schedule.get(i));
        ((ViewGroup) lst_item_view).addView(schedule_view);
    }
    return lst_item_view;
}
```

**Note** different inflate method calls:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null); // no parent
inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_layout, (ViewGroup) lst_item_view, false); // with parent preserving LayoutParams
```

Answer (score 12):

This class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding `View` objects. It is never be used directly -- use `getLayoutInflater()` or `getSystemService(String)` to retrieve a standard `LayoutInflater` instance that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly configured for the device you are running on. For example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: This may be true but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

[LayoutInflater](https://zgrepcode.com/android/9.0.0/base.core/android/view/layoutinflater.java) is a class used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding view objects which can be used in Java programs.
In simple terms, there are two ways to create UI in android. One is a static way and another is dynamic or programmatically.
Suppose we have a simple layout main.xml  having one `textview` and one `edittext` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/namelabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter your name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
    </TextView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10">
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

We can display this layout in static way by

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

A dynamic way of creating a view means the view is not mentioned in our main.xml but we want to show with this in run time. For example, we have another XML in layout folder as  footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Add your record"
    android:textSize="24sp" >
 </TextView>
```

We want to show this textbox in run time within our main UI. So here we will inflate text.xml. See how:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  final LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  TextView t = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer,null);

  lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
  lLayout.addView(t);
```

Here I have used getSystemService (String) to retrieve a  LayoutInflater instance. I can use getLayoutInflator() too to inflate instead of using getSystemService (String) like below:

```
LayoutInflator inflater = getLayoutInflater();
TextView t = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
lLayout.addView(t);
```

Answer (score 8):

Inflating means reading the XML file that describes a layout (or GUI element) and to create the actual objects that correspond to it, and thus make the object visible within an Android app.

```
final Dialog mDateTimeDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

// Inflate the root layout
final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.date_time_dialog, null);

// Grab widget instance
final DateTimePicker mDateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.DateTimePicker);
```

This file could saved as *date_time_dialog.xml*:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DateTimeDialog" android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.dt.datetimepicker.DateTimePicker
            android:id="@+id/DateTimePicker" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ControlButtons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/DateTimePicker"
            android:padding="5dip">
            <Button android:id="@+id/SetDateTime" android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:text="@android:string/ok" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   />
            <Button android:id="@+id/ResetDateTime" android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:text="Reset" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            <Button android:id="@+id/CancelDialog" android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:text="@android:string/cancel" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This file could saved as *date_time_picker.xml*:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" `enter code here`
    android:padding="5dip" android:id="@+id/DateTimePicker">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/month_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/month_plus"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"  
        android:background="@drawable/image_button_up_final"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/month_display"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/picker_middle"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000">
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/month_minus"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"       
        android:background="@drawable/image_button_down_final"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/date_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_plus"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"       
        android:background="@drawable/image_button_up_final"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date_display"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/picker_middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_minus"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"      
        android:background="@drawable/image_button_down_final"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/year_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/year_plus"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"       
            android:background="@drawable/image_button_up_final"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/year_display"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/picker_middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/year_minus"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"       
        android:background="@drawable/image_button_down_final"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hour_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hour_plus"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"          
            android:background="@drawable/image_button_up_final"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hour_display"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/picker_middle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:singleLine="true">
        </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hour_minus"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"       
            android:background="@drawable/image_button_down_final"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/min_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/min_plus"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"       
            android:background="@drawable/image_button_up_final"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/min_display"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/picker_middle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/min_minus"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"       
            android:background="@drawable/image_button_down_final"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/meridiem_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ToggleButton 
            android:id="@+id/toggle_display"
            style="@style/SpecialToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textOn="@string/meridiem_AM"
            android:textOff="@string/meridiem_PM"
            android:checked="true"/>

           <!--  android:checked="true" --> 

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `MainActivity` class saved as *MainActivity.java*:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
    Button button_click;
    public static Activity me = null;
    String meridiem;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        button_click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button_click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                final Dialog mDateTimeDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout)   getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.date_time_dialog, null);
                final DateTimePicker mDateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.DateTimePicker);
                // mDateTimePicker.setDateChangedListener();
                ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDateTimePicker.clearFocus();
                        int hour = mDateTimePicker.getHour();
                        String result_string = mDateTimePicker.getMonth() +" "+   String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getDay()) + ", " + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getYear())
                        + "  " +(mDateTimePicker.getHour()<=9? String.valueOf("0"+mDateTimePicker.getHour()) : String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getHour())) + ":" + (mDateTimePicker.getMinute()<=9?String.valueOf("0"+mDateTimePicker.getMinute()):String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getMinute()))+" "+mDateTimePicker.getMeridiem();
                        editText.setText(result_string);
                        mDateTimeDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                // Cancel the dialog when the "Cancel" button is clicked
                ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.CancelDialog)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mDateTimeDialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                // Reset Date and Time pickers when the "Reset" button is clicked
                ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ResetDateTime)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mDateTimePicker.reset();
                    }
                });

                // Setup TimePicker
                // No title on the dialog window
                mDateTimeDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                // Set the dialog content view
                mDateTimeDialog.setContentView(mDateTimeDialogView);
                // Display the dialog
                mDateTimeDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**What inflater does**

It takes a xml layout as input (say) and converts it to View object.

**Why needed**

Let us think a scenario where we need to create a custom listview. Now each row should be custom. But how can we do it. Its not possible to assign a xml layout to a row of listview. So, we create a View object. Thus we can access the elements in it (textview,imageview etc) and also assign the object as row of listview

So, whenever we need to assign view type object somewhere and we have our custom xml design we just convert it to object by inflater and use it.

Comment: So, Mister Zahan, is it like the DOM in Javascript? •o•

Answer (score 5):

here is an example for geting a refrence for the root View of a layout , 
inflating it and using it with setContentView(View view)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater li=getLayoutInflater();
    View rootView=li.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
    setContentView(rootView);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Layout inflater is a class that reads the xml appearance description and convert them into java based View objects.

Answer (score 1):

LayoutInflater creates View objects based on layouts defined in XML. There are several different ways to use LayoutInflater, including creating custom Views, inflating Fragment views into Activity views, creating Dialogs, or simply inflating a layout file View into an Activity.

There are a lot of misconceptions about how the inflation process works. I think this comes from poor of the documentation for the inflate() method. If you want to learn about the inflate() method in detail, I wrote a blog post about it here:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/

Answer (score 0):

my customize list hope it illustrate concept

```
public class second extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
//  TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//  textview.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("value"));

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.counteries)));
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        String[]items=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.counteries);

        ImageView iv=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(items[position]);

        if(items[position].equals("unitedstates")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.usa);
        }else   if(items[position].equals("Russia")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.russia);
        }else   if(items[position].equals("Japan")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.japan);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return row;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

LayoutInflater is a fundamental component in Android. You must use it all the time to turn xml files into view hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Inflater actually some sort of convert to data,  views, instances, to visible UI representation.. ..thus it make use of data feed into from maybe adapters,  etc. programmatically. then integrating it with an xml you defined, that tells it how the data should be represented in UI