# How to copy all properties of a view?

Tags: android, view

I’m creating an currency exchange rate application to learn Android. The app will list all exchange rate in a list, each of them has the layout like this (in essential):

```
<TableRow>
    <ImageView>
        [properties for the Flag image here]
    </ImageView>
    <TableLayout>
        <TableRow> 
            <TextView> [Buying] </TextView>
            <TextView> [Buying Rate] </TextView>
        </TableRow> 
        <TableRow> 
            <TextView> [Transfer] </TextView>
            <TextView> [Transfer Rate] </TextView>
        </TableRow> 
        <TableRow> 
            <TextView> [Selling] </TextView>
            <TextView> [Selling Rate] </TextView>
        </TableRow> 
    </TableLayout>
</TableRow>
```

To list exchange rate for all currencies I have the following approach:

```
 - Design the layout for one currency (let’s choose EUR as first currency)
 - Generate the layout for all other currencies automatically by:   
1.  Copy all properties of the EUR-layout into the new currency layout
2.  Modify some properties of new currency layout like: ID, Rates …
3.  Repeat steps 1,2 for all sub-layout of the new currency layout
```

But I don’t know how to code step 1, so I did a lot of  google about: “android copy view”  “android copy properties” “android copy view” “android clone view” “java clone object” …. but still no solution. 
**So, my question is:  how to copy all properties of a view ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches:
look at `LayoutInflater` to inflate a sublayout from xml or use a `ListView` (which actually also uses the LayoutInflater in the end.)

Search for LayoutInflater here on SO for samples, i.e.
[What does LayoutInflater in Android do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/layout-inflater-in-android)

Comment: Thank you Mathias,
I have done some reading based on your keywords, and solve the problem: Create a custom list view. Here are some useful reference, I hope they may help some beginner like me in the future: 

- Tutorial - Creating custom list view: 
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ 

- Creating views, which are taylor made to our need:
The book "Professional Android 2 Application Development (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)" - Chapter 4 - Creating New Views

Comment: Your answer helped point me in the right direction. [I made an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41500409/3681880) to illustrate how all the properties of a view could be copied with `LayoutInflater`.