# multicolumn custom list view in android

Tags: android

can any body give example of multicolumn custom list view in android

Thanks

Comment: GridView? And accept some answers, for crying out loud!

Comment: I had to go through the same problem when i started with listview.I have written a post in my blog about this particular topic .. <http://harshaprabha.blogspot.com>

Comment: Android Multi Column ListView example: http://goo.gl/g6onR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have the same problem as I had, there was an answer here:
[How to copy all properties of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518346/how-to-copy-all-properties-of-a-view)