# How to get elements(findViewById) for a layout which is dynamically loaded(setView) in a dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, preferenceactivity

I need to get the EditText that's defined in an xml layout which is dynamically loaded as a view in a preference dialog i.e. :

```
public class ReportBugPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
        super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);   
        builder.setView(LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.preference_report_bug_layout,null));
        EditText edttxtBugDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bug_description_edittext); // NOT WORKING
    }

}
```

**EDIT : SOLUTION** by jjnFord

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);  

    View viewBugReport = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.preference_report_bug,null);
    EditText edttxtBugDesc = (EditText) viewBugReport.findViewById(R.id.bug_description_edittext);

    builder.setView(viewBugReport);



}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you are extending EditTextPreference you can just use the getEditText() method to grab the default text view.  However, since you are setting your own layout this probably won't do what you are looking for.

In your case you should Inflate your XML layout into a View object, then find the editText in the view - then you can pass your view to the builder.  Haven't tried this, but just looking at your code I would think this is possible.

Something like this:

```
View view = (View) LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.preference_report_bug_layout, null);
EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.bug_description_edittext);
builder.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 9):

> LayoutInflater is needed to create (or fill) View based on XML file in
>   runtime. For example if you need to generate views dynamically for
>   your ListView items.
>   [What is the layout inflater in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958897/what-is-the-layout-inflater-in-an-android-application)

1. Create your LayoutInflater:

`LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();`

2. Create your view by inflater refered to your_xml_file:

`View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_file, null);`

3. Find your object in your layout by id.

`TextView textView =
 (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id_in_your_xml_file);`

4. Use your object: i.e.

`textView.setText("Hello!");`