# Android XML primitive access

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I need to edit an xml file, the problem is that I have multiple xmls and in all my classes/activities I can't put the xml as the main View.

So I must acces an xml file without setting it as main view on any activity.Is that even possible?

I mean I can make: View j = (View) findViewById(R.layout.mytest);

But how can I edit a button's text for ex in that mytest.xml file?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. But maybe [LayoutInfater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) is what you are looking for. Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/layout-inflater-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

although you can inflate any layout using `LayoutInflator` and make any changes for that instance in it , but you can not look  for a persistent change in layout . so first `setContentView` , then change for that view only .

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying you want to dynamically edit a layout xml file??? Example, you have a layout like...

```
<LinearLayout>
    ...
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        ...
        android:text="Some text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

...and you want to dynamically edit `android:text="Some text"` at run time???

If so, that isn't the way to do it. Simply leave the `android:text` attribute out of the layout xml and just set the text of the button at runtime.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContenView(R.layout.mytest);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    btn.setText("Whatever");
}
```