# Android: What is inflater in listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am tried to understand inflator in listview but have not been understand. can anybody explain it with straightforward way with example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will find a good discussion of this here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/layout-inflater-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In a nutshell, this class is used to inflate XMLs that define Views and ViewGroups. Inflation is a process that includes: parsing of layout XMLs, creation of appropriate View objects and their addition to view hierarchy.**

This is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects. It is never be used directly -- use getLayoutInflater() or getSystemService(String) to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly configured for the device you are running on. For example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

You can find more info about it here [Layout resources in Android](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/03/26/layout-resources-in-android/)

Comment: Don't forget `View.inflate()`

Answer (score 0):

Inflater in a ListView inflates the layout of each list item.
You can set the layout to be one of the standard layouts or create your own custom layout.