# Android: setImageResource with LayoutInflater

Tags: android, android-view

I have a listView, a main xml file and a customListview xml file.
for my listView I am using a custom ArrayAdapter which I made.

Now, i would like to set an image as a resource in my MainActivity class.
the problem is that the image is in another xml, not in this which i set the contentView.

I am trying this code but nothing happens:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view,null);
ImageView statusOk=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.statusOkImage);
statusOk.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

If interested in all the code, youcan see here:
[ImageView setVisibility(0) and null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311260/imageview-setvisibility0-and-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: I have a listview which has more than one element per row and i would like to set programaticly an image for each row. For example a status image (green / red) for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your get method in base adapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
         holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
         holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityState);
         holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

         holder.statusOk=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }




       statusOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
       holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getCityState());
       holder.txtPhone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getPhone());

       return convertView;
  }

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtCityState;
    TextView txtPhone;

    ImageView statusOk;

 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Anand, but how to get the view on this line: holder.statusOk=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Comment: ohh sorry its not view its converView, you already getting by inflate, in your code.