# how to insert layout to layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got two layouts first and second, I want to insert second to first.
I want to insert second layout into layout that has id @+id/layout
when I press button Get Layout, it show the the second layout on the bottom of button

first layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_get_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Layout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

second layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/card_base"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_cover"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/card_beauty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_0" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
    LinearLayout placeHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewByid(R.id.layout);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.second_layout, placeHolder);
```

Comment: If I need to dynamically insert several layouts (the No of layout is unkown beforehand), how can I do it?

Answer (score 34):

if I understood you right you should use the following code within your first layout

```
<include 
     layout="@layout/second_layout"
     android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:layout_below="@id/buttonId" />
```

and then in your button's action you just use

```
((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.includedLayout)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 11):

## Use [`include`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Here is a somewhat fuller example. The square blue layout is inserted into the main layout using `include`.

[image]

***activity_main.xml***

This is the main layout. The custom layout is referenced using `include`. You can override any of the attributes here, too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <!-- Here is the inserted layout -->
    <include layout="@layout/my_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***my_layout.xml***

This is the custom layout that will be inserted into the main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="My Layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should use this code snippet to add a Layout inside another one.

```
    parentLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    inflateView=View.inflate(this,R.layout.view_video,parentLayout);
```

Here the `parentLayout`is the root View and `R.layout.view_video` is the layout that you need to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutInflator to inflate an external layout into existing layout. Checkout [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) on Android Dev Site for more information about it.