# add an existing XML layout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm going to create a new RelativeLayout with some Text and Image Views programatically and then add it to a parent layout. The question: is it possible to define that layout in XML and then just add it to the parent programatically? Would be a faster way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use inflation:

```
final LayoutInflater lyInflaterForPanel = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout lLayoutPanel = (LinearLayout) lyInflaterForPanel.inflate(
                R.layout.my_row, null);
```

This has worked for me.

Comment: thx, it works. BUT, the layout that I did inflate has some TextViews. I initialized them after inflating the layout and tried to set the text, but it causes crashes. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I think it should work. Can you post logcat with your updated code?

Comment: it gives me a "Delivery Failure" error since I tried so set the text in the OnActivityResult() method (caused by NullPointerException). I did initialize the TextView after inflating its parent layout, but any action other then initialization (findViewById) causes a NullPointerException..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) you will inflate your XML then add it to the parent..

check, [What does LayoutInflater in Android do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/what-does-layout-inflater-in-android-do)

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutInflater class for that. It will covert your layout into a view and add it to parent.