# How to display a TextView from another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, layout-inflater

I have a mainactivity layout and another layout with a textview. I want to set value to textview from my mainactivity file and display it in the mainlayout file. How can I go about this. I'm using layout inflator and am getting the refrence id of Textview successfully.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null); //log.xml is your file.
    TextView tv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);

    System.out.println("Textview= "+tv);
    tv.setText("hELLLLOO");
}
}
```

Main_Layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use intent and pass the value to the next Activity. You only inflate the layout but that is not added to Activity.

You will have to get the reference to `RelativeLayout` and add the inflated view to it

Have a id for RelativeLAyout

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativelayout
```

Then

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null); //log.xml is your file.
TextView tv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
tv.setText("hELLLLOO");
rl.addView(vi);
```

You may also use the

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/

Or

In `MainActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key","hello");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in `SecondActivity`

```
// Inflate Layout 2 and set text to textview.
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like this in **MainActivity.java**

```
View view;
/* We inflate the xml which gives us a view */
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_custom_row, false);

 /* Get the widget with id name which is defined in the xml of the row */
 TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

 /* Populate the row's xml with info from the item */
 name.setText(myObject.getName());
```

Where mInflater is an Object of LayoutInflator.
Or Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/what-does-layout-inflater-in-android-do) link.
hope this helps.