# how to add a view like TextView from another layout to the LinearLayout in current Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

### How to add a view like TextView from another layout to the LinearLayout in current Layout in android .

I want to add TV_Added TextView from items.xml layout to LIN_Main LinearLayout in activity_main.xml Layout .

activity_main.xml layout in my current Layout .
but there is a error .

items.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TV_Added"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LIN_Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testaddview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout LIN_Main;

    TextView TV_GroupTitle;

    LayoutInflater LYOTInf;

    View VIW_AllItems;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        LIN_Main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LIN_Main);

        LYOTInf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        VIW_AllItems = LYOTInf.inflate(R.layout.items,null);

        TV_GroupTitle = (TextView) VIW_AllItems.findViewById(R.id.TV_Added); 

        LIN_Main.addView(TV_GroupTitle);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you are missing `android:id` for the `TextView` inside activity_main.xml?

Comment: well what can i do for this ?

Comment: You can copy the complete TextView block as is. You are trying to retrieve it by id inside the activity and as it does not have an id, it must be failing.

Comment: you are right . but i need to do this . because i want to create a form programmatically .

Comment: and i want to add views from another activity

Comment: then this code is for what ? VIW_AllItems = LYOTInf.inflate(R.layout.items,null);

Comment: Do you want to dynamically add Views which will be similar to your first layout? Please refer this thread if that's the ask, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view

Comment: this code `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), TV_GroupTitle.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
` return value of textview  but i cant add this textview in linearlayout

Comment: thanks for your guide

Answer (score 0):

I find the link that tell about this .
The answer is :

[How to display a TextView from another layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244155/how-to-display-a-textview-from-another-layout)