# Design a RecyclerView with different layouts

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` with different `CardView` layouts.

My question is that if I want to add dynamic list on each `CardView`, then should I add `ListView` on each card or add `RecyclerView` on each card?

An example will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please try to explain a bit more in detail what you are trying to do? As far as I understood, you are trying to put a listview/recyclerview on each card that is itself already inside a recyclerview?

Comment: Correct. This is what I'm trying to do. Is it possible ? recommended ?

Comment: I will put my answer now, hold on

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest it is not very common to add a RecyclerView inside another. It would be better for you to use a single RecyclerView and populate your list items dynamically. Here a github project to describe how this can be done https://github.com/comeondude/dynamic-recyclerview/wiki. 
I'd say have a look. There might be different approaches, this however, is a much faster and efficient way of showing multiple lists in a RecyclerView.

> The idea is to add logic in your onCreateViewHolder and
>   onBindViewHolder method so that you can inflate proper view for the
>   exact positions in your RecyclerView.
>
> There is a sample project along with that wiki too. You might clone
>   and check what it does.
>
> There is another way of keeping your items in a single ArrayList of
>   objects so that you can set an attribute tagging the items to indicate
>   which item is from first list and which one belongs to second list.
>   Then pass that ArrayList into your RecyclerView and then implement the
>   logic inside adapter to populate them dynamically.
>   [How to add a recyclerView inside another recyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569217/how-to-add-a-recyclerview-inside-another-recyclerview)

Tell me if this solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

in .onCreateViewHolder() method you receive int variable viewType
Use it for distinguishing between different layout types