# How to have a recycler view in a recycler view using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So, I am trying to design a Android Application but I am stuck!! I am trying to create a activity where I will be retrieving data from the firebase database in a recycler view (easy up to now). After I retrieve that data, I need to retrieve more data using a recycler view inside the previous recycler view!!!
If someone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it! (I could provide more information about the app)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569217/how-to-add-a-recyclerview-inside-another-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Use Expandable Listview.It would be easy as it uses Hashmap and list.