# Recyclerview as an item of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout, nestedrecyclerview

I have two recyclerviews, both of them are vertical. These two have seperate adapters and outer one is grid layout manager. On the other hand, inner recyclerview has staggered layout manager.

[image: Sample layout definition]

Inner recyclerview never scrolls because of its parent scrolling however, inner recyclerview also never calls detach for its viewholders. So, it draws all items at once. Is there a way to make it recycle to its views?

Comment: Show your codes so that everyone can view  and suggest you.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569217/how-to-add-a-recyclerview-inside-another-recyclerview