# Best practice for displaying list inside RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am wondering what would be best practice to display small list of items inside ViewHolder?

Should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39060431/10326629) and [this project](https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview/wiki)

The second way is to create [nested RecyclerViews](https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047)

Comment: first approach is basically creating different ViewHolders in same RecyclerView. Second one maybe worth a trying, but I am wondering is it okay to put another RecyclerView in ViewHolder

Comment: Well, the second way is a common practice.