# Scrolling RecyclerView inside a RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with some dummy string data in each item. Each item has also a recyclerview which contains some other dummy data (A - Z, see below) that will be visible when a button is clicked.

The problem I have is that I can not scroll the recyclerview within the item as I want. When I scroll, only the outer recyclerview scrolls (as you seen below)

Here how is it look like: 
[image]

Here are the code I wrote:

```
//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private StringAdapter mStringAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStrings.add("This");
        mStrings.add("is");
        mStrings.add("a");
        mStrings.add("test");


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mStringAdapter = new StringAdapter(mStrings, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mStringAdapter);

    }
}
```

Here, the adapter resonsible for the outer main recyclerview. Note that the recyclerview of each main recyclerview item gets visible when the button is clicked :

```
public class StringAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StringAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mStrings;
    private Context mContext;
    private SomeInnerDataAdapter mSomeInnerDataAdapter;

    public StringAdapter(ArrayList<String> strings, Context context) {
        mStrings = strings;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StringAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);

        return new StringAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StringAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String text = mStrings.get(i);
        viewHolder.onBindText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mStrings.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mTextView;
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        private Button mButton;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.someOtherData);
            mButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

                    strings.add("A");
                    strings.add("B");
                    strings.add("C");
                    strings.add("D");
                    strings.add("E");
                    strings.add("F");
                    strings.add("G");
                    strings.add("H");
                    strings.add("I");
                    strings.add("J");
                    strings.add("K");
                    strings.add("L");
                    strings.add("M");
                    strings.add("N");
                    strings.add("O");
                    strings.add("P");
                    strings.add("R");
                    strings.add("S");
                    strings.add("T");
                    strings.add("U");
                    strings.add("V");
                    strings.add("W");
                    strings.add("X");
                    strings.add("Y");
                    strings.add("Z");


                    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                    mSomeInnerDataAdapter = new SomeInnerDataAdapter(strings, mContext);

                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSomeInnerDataAdapter);
                }
            });
        }

        public void onBindText(String text){
            mTextView.setText(text);


        }
    }
}
```

The adapter responsible for the recyclerview within a item:

```
public class SomeInnerDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeInnerDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mStrings;
    private Context mContext;

    public SomeInnerDataAdapter(ArrayList<String> strings, Context context) {
        mStrings = strings;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SomeInnerDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.someotherdata_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SomeInnerDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String text = mStrings.get(i);
        viewHolder.onBindString(text);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mStrings.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.someotherdata_textview);
        }

        public void onBindString(String text){
            mTextView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

The xml layouts are the following:

```
// item.xml
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/someOtherData"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="show comment"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and someotherdata_item.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/someotherdata_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: read the answer here it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/39060431/11266036