# Add items within nested list within nested recyclerview in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I have a recyclerview and within it I am trying to add a nested recyclerview that contains a list. Here is what I am trying to make: 
[image: My Desired output]

[This is the closest solution I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39060431/8191265) on stack overflow but they use headers instead of left-aligned titles that wrap all other nested views. How do I create a nested list within a nested recyclerview within a recyclerview?

Comment: We need two recyclerViews and two Adapters which i call inner and outter.inside ViewHolder of outter adapter put innerRecyclerview and inside onBindViewHolder of outter adapter set adapter to innerRecyclerView

Comment: @SalarArabpour This sounds like a good solution. Do you think my approach to the idea could be better? I feel like I am thinking of using too many recycler views to get what I want. I am only trying to make a dynamic list of items within a main list of fixed items.

Comment: I can assure you doing this with two recyclerviews is the best option. I will post you an example code tommorow when i access my laptop!

Comment: @SalarArabpour you are incredible!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need two RecyclerViews and two Adapters which i call inner and outer.inside ViewHolder of outer adapter put innerRecyclerView and inside onBindViewHolder of outer adapter set adapter to innerRecyclerView.i recently developed a test project like this

**here is outerAdapter**

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Category> categories;
private List<Ads> ads_list;
private List<Products> productsList;
private int count;
private int width;

public MainAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categories, List<Ads> ads_list,List<Products> productsList,int width) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categories = categories;
    this.ads_list = ads_list;
    this.productsList=productsList;
    this.width=width;
    //Helper.logDebug("main__adapter",String.valueOf(categories.size()));
    //Helper.logDebug("main_adapter","haminjoori");
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView tv_type,ad_tv_image_address;
    private ImageView iv_ad;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        recyclerView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_horizental);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        tv_type=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
        iv_ad=itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_ad);
        ad_tv_image_address=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_image_address);
        //Helper.logDebug("main_adapter","haminjoori");
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout,viewGroup,false);
    //Helper.logDebug("main_adapter","haminjoori");
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ViewHolder holder= (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
    try {
        String banner_url=ads_list.get(i).getImage();
        holder.ad_tv_image_address.setText(banner_url);
        Picasso.get().load(context.getString(R.string.base_url_banner)+banner_url).into(holder.iv_ad);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        holder.ad_tv_image_address.setText("");
    }
    Helper.logDebug("main_adapter",holder.ad_tv_image_address.getText().toString());
    holder.tv_type.setText(categories.get(i).getName());
    SecondAdapter secondAdapter=new SecondAdapter(categories.get(i).getProducts(),context,width);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

    holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(secondAdapter);



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categories.size();
}
}
```

**and here is inner adapter**

```
public class SecondAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private int count;
private List<Products> productsList;
private List<Category> categories;
private int width;

public SecondAdapter(List<Products> productsList, Context context,int width) {
    this.productsList = productsList;
    this.context = context;
    this.width=width;
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView market_price,our_price,name,unit,min_amount,image;
    private ImageView imagee;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.getLayoutParams().width=width/2;


        market_price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_market_price);
        our_price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_our_price);
        name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fruit_name);
        unit=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fruit_unit);
        image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image_url);
        imagee=itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_rec);
        min_amount=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_min_amount);

        Log.d("second_adapter","haminjoori");
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler2_layout,viewGroup,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ViewHolder holder= (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
    Helper.logDebug("second_adapter","haminjori");

    holder.name.setText(productsList.get(i).getName());
    holder.unit.setText(productsList.get(i).getUnit());
    holder.market_price.setText(String.valueOf(productsList.get(i).getMarketPrice()));
    holder.our_price.setText(String.valueOf(productsList.get(i).getOurPrice()));
    Helper.logDebug("secondAdapter",productsList.get(i).getImage());
    String address=productsList.get(i).getImage();
    address=address.substring(6);
    holder.image.setText(address);
    String full_address=context.getString(R.string.base_url_image)+address;
    Helper.logDebug("secondAdapter",full_address);
    Picasso.get().load(full_address).into(holder.imagee);
    holder.min_amount.setText(String.valueOf(productsList.get(i).getMin_amount()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    Helper.logDebug("second_adapter",String.valueOf(productsList.size()));
    return productsList.size();
}
}
```

**outer view adapter xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"         
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="نوع میوه" 
  android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" style="@style/main_titles" 
  android:id="@+id/tv_type"/>

  <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp" 
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/recyclerview_horizental" 
  android:layout_below="@id/tv_type" 
  app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" 
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  tools:listitem="@layout/recycler2_layout"/>

  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ad_image_address" 
  android:visibility="gone"/>

  <ImageView android:layout_height="80dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/iv_ad" 
  android:layout_below="@id/recyclerview_horizental"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**inner view adapter xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" 
android:id="@+id/rel_layout">

<ImageView android:layout_height="200dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/iv_rec"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/fruit_name" 
android:textColor="@color/semi_black" android:textSize="14sp" 
android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_below="@id/iv_rec" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="نام میوه"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/fruit_unit" 
android:textColor="@color/black_white" android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_below="@id/iv_rec" android:text="واحد" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/product_market_price" 
android:textColor="@color/semi_black" android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_below="@id/fruit_unit" android:text="قیمت مارکت" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/product_our_price" 
android:textColor="@color/semi_black" android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_below="@id/product_market_price" android:text="قیمت ما" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/product_min_amount" 
android:textColor="@color/semi_black" android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_below="@id/product_market_price" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/product_image_url" 
android:textColor="@color/semi_black" android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_below="@id/product_market_price" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" 
android:visibility="gone"> </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

final result will be something like this...(this is something similar,not exactly what xml file is)

[image]

categories are outer `RecyclerView` and fruits are inner `RecyclerView`

ask me if you have problem implementating this...

Comment: Fantastic! I got it working on android studio. Just one question: How do you make the categories wrap the product list on the left instead of as a header? I was able to make the inner recyclerview vertical and am now trying to center the category titles both vertically and horizontally to the left of the product list

Comment: easiest way would be wrapping title TextView in a RelativeLayout. TextView with xml attribute android:centerVertical="true"

Comment: May I please see your xml layouts?

Comment: i have added xml layouts too,but remember that screenshot is something similar and not exactly what xml code is,i just could'nt build project and found a similar screenshot from website of that customer

Comment: Thank you! I marked your solution as the answer. Just one last question: how do I edit the data in the inner adapter through the outer adapter? Like lets say when I click on the mango, I want the mango visibility to be `GONE`. How do I do that? Thank you for your time!!

Comment: thank you Bread,you can do that in on click of inner adapter.look at this example...holder.btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                list.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

Comment: Very good and easy explanation. Thanks

Comment: what about saving scroll state of inner adapter?