# How to use String[] in custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-listview, custom-adapter

I make a custom adapter, that should call the custom arraylist java class, so that it will show 3 seperate string array. However, if i put the String[] in the custom arraylist java class, it will not work with the custom adapter, as getitem(position) will need int type of getArabic. So how do i make it ?

here is my custom arraylist java

```
public class Perrow {

    String[] Arabic;
    String[] transliteration;
    String[] translation;

    public Perrow(String[] arabic, String[] transliteration, String[] translation) {
        Arabic = arabic;
        this.transliteration = transliteration;
        this.translation = translation;
    }

    public String[] getArabic() {
        return Arabic;
    }

    public void setArabic(String[] arabic) {
        Arabic = arabic;
    }

    public String[] getTransliteration() {
        return transliteration;
    }

    public void setTransliteration(String[] transliteration) {
        this.transliteration = transliteration;
    }

    public String[] getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String[] translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }
}
```

and my custom adapter

```
public class PerrowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Perrow> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;



    public PerrowAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Perrow> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mResource = resource;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView arabictext = convertView.findViewById(R.id.arabictext);
        TextView transliteration = convertView.findViewById(R.id.transliteration);
        TextView translation = convertView.findViewById(R.id.translation);

        String[] arabica = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fontsize);

        arabictext.setText(getItem(position).getArabic(arabica));
        transliteration.setText(getItem(position).getTransliteration());
        translation.setText(getItem(position).getTranslation());












        return convertView;
    }
}
```

really appreciate help thank you everyone

Comment: Why Are you using String [] , you are already passing ArrayList of object

Comment: I have addressed a similar problem here in my Github project. You might consider take a look here - https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview
Here's a SO thread that tries to solve a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569217/how-to-add-a-recyclerview-inside-another-recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is trying to set `array` as a text to `TextView` like below code.

```
arabictext.setText(getItem(position).getArabic(arabica));
transliteration.setText(getItem(position).getTransliteration());
translation.setText(getItem(position).getTranslation());
```

If you want to get String for a specific index you can just use it's index. For example:

```
arabictext.setText(getItem(position).getArabic()[0]);
transliteration.setText(getItem(position).getTransliteration()[0]);
translation.setText(getItem(position).getTranslation()[0]);
```

Or If you want to get all values from `String[]` as one `String` and set it to your `TextView` you can create a method which gets an `String[]` and returns `String`.

```
private String getString(String[] array){
    String text = "";
    for (String s : array) {
        text += s + ", ";
    }
    return text;
}
```

So inside your adapter define a method like above and whenever you need a `String` from `String[]` use that method.

```
public class PerrowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Perrow> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;
    private ArrayList<Perrow> objects;

    public PerrowAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Perrow> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mResource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    private String getString(String[] array){
        String text = "";
        for (String s : array) {
            text += s + ", ";
        }
        return text;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView tvArabic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.arabictext);
        TextView tvTransliteration = convertView.findViewById(R.id.transliteration);
        TextView tvTranslation = convertView.findViewById(R.id.translation);

        Perrow perrow = objects.get(position);
        String[] arabica = perrow.getArabic();
        String[] transliteration = perrow.getTransliteration();
        String[] translation = perrow.getTranslation();

        tvArabic.setText(getString(arabica));
        tvTransliteration.setText(getString(transliteration));
        tvTranslation.setText(getString(translation));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

> i want as per row of the listview, show each item in the string array, >accordingly. how can this be achieved ?

You should change your `Perrow` class and instead of `String[]` use `String` and populate your `ArrayList` with each elements of `String[]`.

Perrow.java (use `String` instead of `String[]`)

```
public class Perrow {
    String Arabic;
    String transliteration;
    String translation;

    public Perrow(String arabic, String transliteration, String translation) {
        Arabic = arabic;
        this.transliteration = transliteration;
        this.translation = translation;
    }

    public String getArabic() {
        return Arabic;
    }

    public void setArabic(String arabic) {
        Arabic = arabic;
    }

    public String getTransliteration() {
        return transliteration;
    }

    public void setTransliteration(String transliteration) {
        this.transliteration = transliteration;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }
}
```

PerrowAdapter.java (`get()` methods from `Perrow` class now return `String` so you can directly use them for `TextView`s)

```
public class PerrowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Perrow> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;
    private ArrayList<Perrow> objects

    public PerrowAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Perrow> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mResource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView tvArabic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.arabictext);
        TextView tvTransliteration = convertView.findViewById(R.id.transliteration);
        TextView tvTranslation = convertView.findViewById(R.id.translation);

        Perrow perrow = objects.get(position);

        tvArabic.setText(perrow.getArabic());
        tvTransliteration.setText(perrow.getTransliteration());
        tvTranslation.setText(perrow.getTranslation());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I don't know how do you fill your `String[]` but I assume all three `String[]` have same length (arrays contain same number `Strings`), so you can add all `Strings` in to `ArrayList` with a `for` loop and use that `ArrayList` for your adapter.

Your Activiy (where do you call `PerrowAdapter`)

```
String[] arabica = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fontsize);
String[] trasliteration = ... //Get your trasliteration array
String[] translation = ... //Get your translation array

ArrayList<Perrow> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < arabica.length; i++){
    list.add(new Perrow(arabica[i], transliteration[i], translation[i]));
}

PerrowAdapter adapter = new PerrowAdapter(context, resource, list);
```

Comment: Thank you it does work if i want a specific index of string, or put the whole string array in the textview. But, i want as per row of the listview, show each item in the string array, accordingly. how can this be achieved ?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH IM STUCKED IN THIS PROBLEMS FOR LIKE A WEEK :) really appreciate it