# recyclerview not showing full list of android studio data

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

I am making an android application using java and xml, the application allows to debate by generating arguments and counter arguments. To display the argument list create an "external" recyclerview that inflates a view which contains linear layout. To display the list of counter arguments create an internal recyclerview that inflates a view which contains a cardview which allows counterarguments on a specific argument. The problem is that the internal recyclerview does not show the complete list of counterarguments. I leave you part of my code hoping that you can help me

adapterArgument.class

```
public class adapterArguments extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterArguments.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ListArguments> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    public String position_selected;
    public static String argument;




    public adapterArguments(List<ListArguments> itemList, Context context) {
        this.data = itemList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.compontents_arguments_recyclerview,null);
        return new adapterArguments.ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ConexionSQliteHelper conn=new ConexionSQliteHelper(context,"db_testwuad_7",null,31);
        holder.arguments.setText(data.get(position).getArguments());
        holder.name_user.setText(data.get(position).getName_user());
        holder.date.setText(data.get(position).getDate_arguments());
        holder.position.setText(data.get(position).getPosition());
        int id_argument_selected = data.get(position).getId();
        position_selected = holder.position.getText().toString();
        holder.list_contrarguments = conn.getContrarguments(id_argument_selected);
        holder.recyclerView_contrarguments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        holder.recyclerView_contrarguments.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.listContrarguments = new adapterContrarguments(holder.list_contrarguments,context);
        holder.recyclerView_contrarguments.setAdapter(holder.listContrarguments);
        final int[] checkedItem = {-1};
        if(position_selected.equals("A favor")){
            holder.position.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#073FD7"));
        }
        else{
            holder.position.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FC0C1E"));

        }

        holder.addContrarguments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                alertDialog.setTitle("Añadir un Contrargumento");
                alertDialog.setMessage("¿Quieres añadir un contrargumento a este texto?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                argument = holder.arguments.getText().toString();
                                contrargument fragment = new contrargument();
                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putString("argument", argument);
                                args.putInt("id",id_argument_selected);
                                fragment.setArguments(args);
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager;
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
                                fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog customAlertDialog = alertDialog.create();
                customAlertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        holder.deleteDiscuss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                alertDialog.setTitle("¿Deseas eliminar este argumento?");
                alertDialog.setMessage("¿Quieres añadir un contrargumento a este texto?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        boolean user_create_debate = conn.verifyCreatorDebate(holder.name_user.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "el valor es"+user_create_debate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(user_create_debate){
                            conn.deleteArgument(id_argument_selected);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No puede eliminar el argumento,ya que no es el creador del texto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        opinionUserOnPostDebate fragment = new opinionUserOnPostDebate();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
                        fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment).attach(fragment).commit();

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog customAlertDialog = alertDialog.create();
                customAlertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        holder.changePosition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Cambio de postura");
                final String[] listItems = new String[]{"Cambie de opinión","Me equivoque de botón","Otro"};
                alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, checkedItem[0], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        checkedItem[0] = which;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(position_selected.equals("A favor")){
                           //conn.changePosition(id_argument_selected,"En contra");
                        }
                        else{
                            //conn.changePosition(id_argument_selected,"A favor");

                        }

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog customAlertDialog = alertDialog.create();
                customAlertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        holder.Report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Reportar post");
                final String[] listItems = new String[]{"Opinión contiene lenguaje ofensivo","Opinión contiene información personal","Otro"};
                alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, checkedItem[0], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        checkedItem[0] = which;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(position_selected.equals("A favor")){
                            //conn.changePosition(id_argument_selected,"En contra");
                        }
                        else{
                            //conn.changePosition(id_argument_selected,"A favor");

                        }

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog customAlertDialog = alertDialog.create();
                customAlertDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView arguments,name_user,date,position;
        ImageButton addContrarguments,deleteDiscuss,addFriend,changePosition,Report;
        List<ListContrarguments> list_contrarguments;
        RecyclerView recyclerView_contrarguments;
        public adapterContrarguments listContrarguments;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            arguments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.arguments_posted);
            name_user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_arguments);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_arguments);
            position = itemView.findViewById(R.id.position);
            addContrarguments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            deleteDiscuss = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            changePosition = itemView.findViewById(R.id.change_position);
            addFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_friend);
            Report = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_argument);
            recyclerView_contrarguments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_contrargument);



        }
    }
}
```

layout.compontents_arguments_recyclerview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/position"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:background="#0AA842">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_person_contrarguments"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_arguments"
                android:layout_width="145dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                >

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_arguments"
                android:layout_width="145dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                >

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="360dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/arguments_posted"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                >

            </TextView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="#FEFEFE"
                >
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/comments"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_comments"
                    android:background="#FEFEFE"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    >
                </ImageButton>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/delete"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/delete"
                    android:background="#FEFEFE"
                    >
                </ImageButton>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/change_position"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/change_opinion"
                    android:background="#FEFEFE"
                    >

                </ImageButton>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/add_friend"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_friend"
                    android:background="#FEFEFE"
                    >
                </ImageButton>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/report_argument"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/display_report"
                    android:background="#FEFEFE"
                    >
                </ImageButton>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#A4A1A1"
                >
            </View>
            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="179dp"
                layout="@layout/recyclerview_contrarguments"
                >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

adapterContrarguments.class

```
public class adapterContrarguments extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterContrarguments.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ListContrarguments> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public adapterContrarguments(List<ListContrarguments> itemlist, Context context) {
        this.data = itemlist;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_contrarguments,null);
        return new adapterContrarguments.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name_user_posted_contrarguments.setText(data.get(position).getName_user_posted_contrarguments());
        holder.contrarguments.setText(data.get(position).getPost_contrarguments());
        holder.date_contrarguments.setText(data.get(position).getDate_contrarguments());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name_user_posted_contrarguments,date_contrarguments,contrarguments;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name_user_posted_contrarguments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_post_contrargument);
            date_contrarguments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_contrargument);
            contrarguments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contrargument_post);
        }
    }
}
```

cardview_contrarguments.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:padding="26dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_post_contrargument"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contrargument_post"
            android:layout_width="336dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_contrargument"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.89"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant get a recyclerview inside a recyclerview. If the number of counter argument is constant for every external recyclerview item, like every argument has 4 counter argument, then I suggest you to add counter arguments design to arguments xml.
Maybe check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569217/how-to-add-a-recyclerview-inside-another-recyclerview)

Comment: the list of counterarguments will never be constant for each argument. Thanks for replying