# extends BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm new to Android programming, and I'm studying how to create a personal Adapter for a ListView and on tutorial in the new Adapter's constructor has this lines:

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Recipe> mDataSource;

    public RecipeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipe> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataSource = items;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

}
```

The tutorial doesn't describe what is exactly `Context` and what this line does: `mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` and I dont understand it.

Can you describe them?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a tutorial about extending from the BaseAdapter class: http://abhiandroid.com/ui/baseadapter-tutorial-example.html

EDIT

context is the "context" the active activity "lives" in.  From this context you get the inflater. The inflater is used to inflate xml layouts you created for your listview.

Additional information about context
Related SO question [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)

Additional inrormtion about the layoutinflater 
Related SO question [What does LayoutInflater in Android do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/what-does-layoutinflater-in-android-do)

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.