# Update the DrawingCache of a specific layout in Android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-edittext, drawingcache

I have problem on getting the correct "ScreenShot" of a layout in android. The layout contains EditTexts and TextViews.

The following code only give an "ScreenShot" of the Layout, but when I changed the string in EditText or TextView the "ScreenShot" do not updated!

How can I ensure that the "ScreenShot" can be updated and be the same as shown on the screen?

```
private Bitmap getBitmap() {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    LayoutInflater factorys = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = factorys.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    View ll = textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.ll_layout);
    ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    ll.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    ll.layout(0, 0, ll.getMeasuredWidth(), ll.getMeasuredHeight());
    ll.buildDrawingCache();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ll.getDrawingCache());
    //bitmap=getCacheBitmapFromView(ll);
    ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Here is the whole code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(mycl);
    }

    OnClickListener mycl = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bitmap mybpic = null;
            mybpic = getBitmap();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mybpic);
        }
    };

    private Bitmap getBitmap() {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        LayoutInflater factorys = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factorys.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
                null);
        View ll = textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.ll_layout);

        ll.destroyDrawingCache();
        ll.invalidate();
        ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        ll.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec
                .makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        ll.layout(0, 0, ll.getMeasuredWidth(), ll.getMeasuredHeight());
        ll.buildDrawingCache();

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ll.getDrawingCache());
        // bitmap=getCacheBitmapFromView(ll);
        ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding ll.destroyDrawingCache();   before ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Comment: I tried both   
  ll.destroyDrawingCache();
        ll.invalidate(); 
it does not work for me 
@DivyeshPatel

Comment: try to invalidate for edittext and textview

Comment: Solved, I should not use 

> LayoutInflater
@DivyeshPatel

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I should not use

> LayoutInflater

LayoutInflater  just Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding android.view.View objects, but not the current graphic
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477483/8550665)

just use findViewbyId to get the View Object 
then

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap drawingCache = view.getDrawingCache();
```

that works!