# LayoutInflater how excatly make the new View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, layout-inflater

I've read one of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/what-does-layoutinflater-in-android-do), and I am still confused.

""When I first started Android programming, I was really confused by LayoutInflater and findViewById. Sometimes we used one and sometimes the other.

LayoutInflater is used to create a new View (or Layout) object from one of your xml layouts.

findViewById just gives you a reference to a view than has already been created. You might think that you haven't created any views yet, but whenever you call setContentView in onCreate, the activity's layout along with its subviews gets inflated (created) behind the scenes."

I think I understand so when LayoutInflater creat a new object View, why we can't just do this:

`view = new View(context);`

`view = findViewById(R.id.textView);`

I missed something ? Thank you for anwsere.

I tried to undestrand way of working LayOutInflater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words: `LayoutInflater` helps you to "exchange" layout written in XML to code, its kind of parser which take XML input and creates proper `View`s using `Context` (some simple way of `new View` object creation in first code line in your question).

`Activity` does that under the hood giving us devs simple `setContentView` and `findViewById` methods, but you may also want to add some custom `View` defined in XML additionally (because some `if`) or doring runtime, then you can use `LayoutInflater` based on same `Context` which views already created/shown are using (e.g. `Activity` itself).

Note that when you use `setContentView` then `LayoutInflater` will attach some XML-based `View`s to `Activity`, so further line

```
view = findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

will return reference to already inflated existing `View`, meanwhile

```
view = new View(context)
```

is just creating some dummy `View` in memory using context, it isn't added to `Activity`, `Fragment`, any shown `ViewGroup`, thus is not even visible (and its not same `view` instance than one found with `findViewById`).

Comment: these are not same views, first one is temporary, not visible, second one, if not null (so added) will return some view from earlier inflated `R.layout` file, doen by `LayoutInflater` also, but by `Activity` itself under the hood. note `Fragment`s have some different API, more GUI-oriented, in there you should use inflater in `onCreateView`

Comment: just think about it like about XML parser: takes first line of text, ok its `LineatLayout`, so it creates `new LinearLayout(context)`, then next item in XML is `TextView` inside `LinearLayout` tag, so inflater creates `new TextView(context)`, sets its attributes from XML (probably every xml param has representation in code setting), and at the end `firstLinearLayout.addView(textView)`. at the end inflater returns built `View` which is probably an instance of `ViewGroup` - main holder of all your views in XML

Comment: if you want to know what `new View(...)` does - thats creation of object, memory allocation etc. Note `new` is keyword of Java, thats "feature" of language (object creation, not every lang is object-oriented), not even Android-only. `findViewById` method of particular framework - Android - and is getting reference to obejct which was also created in similar way, but "autmatically" by inflater basing on given XML

Comment: thats not so kind to remove comments, mine are now out of topic...

Comment: Thumbs up for you, thanks.  I see lack of my knowledge in many terms you using. I will try to learn more about this term and maybe later i will understand this, for know i will be using this as a template :) Thanks again

Comment: for now, at the begin of your Android journey, focus on `findViewById`, also get familiar with `Fragment`. further inspect `Compose`, thats pretty new way, XML-less. if you want to stick with XMLs read about "layout binding", il will do even more work for you it that topic making `Activity` code cleaner

Comment: if you found my answer and comments helpful then think about upvoting and/or accepting my answer :) good luck!

Comment: I can't upvoting cous of lack reputation but I accept your anwser at least I can do this. Thanks again, best wishes.